# What does "saw" mean in "operations that saw many revolutionaries executed"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Here is the quote from [cnn.com](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/05/09/asia/japan-indian-freedom-fighter-hnk-intl/index.html):

> Undeterred, Bose moved the start of the rebellion to February 19 -- but the simultaneous plot was suppressed by counter-intelligence operations that **saw** many revolutionaries executed, imprisoned and exiled.

The definition of **see** I think fits this context is the following (from [here](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/see_1)):

> if a place or a period of time sees an event, the event happens in that place or during that time (The region has seen some of the fiercest fighting in the war.)

The place/period being "the plot being suppressed by intelligence operations" and the event being "many revolutionaries executed, imprisoned and exiled".

Have I got this right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The verb ***to see*** has a large multiplicity of senses, many of which have no direct connection to eyesight - e.g. *I can see why he would think that*; *she lived to see her 100th birthday*; *he saw the visitor to the waiting taxi*, *the doctor will see you in fifteen minutes*.

But it is the OED sense 23b(c), which perhaps comes closest to what you have observed.

> 23**b (c). transitive. Of a time, place, or other context: to be the
>   setting in which (an event, development, etc.) takes place. In later
>   use sometimes with causative sense: to result in (an event,
>   development, etc.). Cf. witness v. 4b. Also with complement expressing
>   the event, development, etc.**
>
> 1643   Earl of Newcastle Answer Late Declar. Ld. Fairefax 5   England
>   did never see such..a Challenge of Military Supremacy.
>
> 1739   C. Wesley in J. Wesley & C. Wesley Hymns & Sacred Poems ii. 211
>   Hail the Day that sees Him rise, Ravish'd from our wishful Eyes.
>
> a1771   T. Gray Ode in W. Mason Mem. Life & Writings (1775) 236   The
>   sullen year Saw the snowy whirlwind fly.
>
> 1837   A. Alison Hist. Europe from French Revol. VI. xlvii. 399
>   Eighteen rivers have seen their navigation improved.
>
> 1868   New Eng. Base Ballist 6 Aug. 3/1   The second inning saw a
>   change as the Champions went out for two runs.
>
> 1895   F. B. Workman & W. H. Workman Algerian Mem. 77   A bright cold
>   morning saw us in the saddle at 6.15.
>
> 1907   A. Lang Hist. Scotl. IV. 408   In 1906 Cambridge saw three or
>   four of her most learned men compete for the Greek chair.
>
> 1981   Times 14 Apr. 22/2   Interim results from Burton saw 2p advance
>   to 137p.
>
> 1993   Age (Melbourne) (Nexis) 1 Oct. 29   An injury-time goal saw the
>   team go out to Levski Sofia.
>
> 2011   Atlantic Nov. 116   Recent years have seen an explosion of male
>   joblessness.

Sense 24d, is also of interest.

> **24d. transitive. Of a thing: to undergo, be subjected to (use, wear,
>   etc.).**
>
> 1839   L. M. Sargent As Med. 41 in Temperance Tales VI.   A dirty,
>   broken tumbler, which had evidently seen hard service in its day.
>
> 1847   M. L. Sweetser Double Courtship vi. 40   The invalid drew on an
>   over-coat which had seen much wear and many repairs.
>
> 1916   Amer. Man. Presswork 5/2   Since there were no duplicating
>   machines and no typewriters in those days, the Army press saw plenty
>   of use.
>
> 1991   Bicycle Guide Sept. 71/1   The small chainring is an essential
>   part of any mountain bike that sees action in speed-limiting zones.
>
> 2015   Belfast Tel. (Nexis) 19 Sept. 13   Given the amount of
>   footfall, the magnificent bar has seen some wear and tear.